# semisimple category and characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $A$ be an algebra and $\mathcal F$ be a category of finite-dimensional $A$-modules over $\mathbb C$ which is completely reducible. Then is it true that in this category the characters determine the modules completely ? That means is it true that if $ch(V)=ch(W)$ for two $G$-modules $V$ and $W$ in $\mathcal F$, then $V \cong W$ ?

Comment: Say there is an abelian subalgebra $H$ of $A$ for which the modules have a weight space decomposition: $V=\oplus_{\mu \in H^*} V_{\mu}$. Then define the formal character to be $ch(V)=\sum_{\mu} dim(V_{\mu})e^{\mu}$.